# flash as3 cannot create property 0 on boolean?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a platform game with flash cs4 and I came across this error. It happens when the player shoots the enemy and my bullet class collides with my enemy class. here is my code the error is in the enemyDead[i] = true; line

```
if(enemyList.length>0) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++) {
            if (bulletList.length>0) {
                for (var j:int = 0; j < bulletList.length; j++) {
                    if (enemyList[i].hitTestObject(bulletList[j])) {
                        trace("Bullet and Enemy are colliding");
                        enemyList[i].gotoAndPlay("dead");
                        enemyDead[i] = true;
                        bulletList[j].removeSelf();
                        enemyList[i].xSpeedConst=0;
                    } else if(enemyList.length>0){
                        enemyDead = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The enemyDead is of course a boolean variable which seems to be causing the problem. Ive been working on this fix for hours but have no idea how (I am noob) everything is working properly except the enemy keeps moving even though I set the xspeedConst property to 0 and the bullet does not remove itself please help

Comment: I first tried adding enemyDead = true; without the [i] but it worked horribly, any help is much appreciated

Comment: What's `enemyDead` ? an Array or a Boolean ?

Comment: Please use the debugger and point out the exact line throwing the error.  Most likely you mean to do:  `enemyList[i].enemyDead = true;` (as your enemyDead flag should likely be a property of an enemy object).  OR, if it's a separate array, then your else if should be:  `enemyDead[i] = false;` as otherwise you're setting it to a boolean instead of an array

Comment: enemyDead is a boolean, should I make it an array? I tried your enemyList[i].enemyDead = true; and it said cannot create property enemy
Dead on Enemy

Comment: You'd have to open your enemy class up and add the property.  `public var enemyDead:Boolean = false;`

Answer (score 2):

The root of your issue is likely that you are trying to use a var in two different ways.

In your hit test,  you do:

```
enemyDead[i] = true;
```

This assumes that the `enemyDead` var is either an array or an object with a property corresponding to the value contained in `i`.

However, in the hist test else if statement later, you do this:

```
enemyDead = false;
```

Which is now treating the `enemyDead` var like a primitive boolean.  If that var is a primitive boolean, then the above (`enemyDead[i] = true`) will error because a boolean doesn't have properties (so if `i` were 0, there is no enemyDead.0 property to set).

Your solution, is to make sure that enemyDead var is used consistently.  You've said it's a boolean, but it would seem to make more sense if it was tied to the individual objects in your `enemyList` array. (right now, you have a single enemyDead var and it's value will be overwritten every iteration through your array leaving it with the value of the last item when the for loop is finished)

I'd recommend modifying your enemy class to include an `isDead` property:

```
//in your Enemy.as file:
public var isDead:Boolean = false;
```

Then set that in your hit test:

```
enemyList[i].isDead = true;
```

Comment: yes that seems to be the problem, any idea how to fix it though? I tried setting the enemyDead = false; property to a var s I made enemyDead[s] = false; but it only made things worse. i appreciate you trying to help

Comment: I added a recommended solution.

Comment: @Dan - did you get this all figured out?   If this led you to your solution, please accept the answer, if not, you can answer the question yourself.  An accepted answer is good for future visitors to quickly find answers.